# Change the value of a class created by jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I try to change the value of a class created by jQuery UI but I can't.
Thank's to tell me how I can do that.

**HTML**

```
<div id="barre" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 960px; height: 540px;">
    <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 48.9583%;"></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".ui-slider-handle").css("height", "100px"); // doesn't modify the value
```

Comment: Assigning height to an inline element (span) doesn't do anything.

Comment: I tried out with the same code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sLLzf2mu/). Seems to work here. I can see from developer tools that the height is added.

Comment: @SamGhatak : But did it has any effect on height? Try gradually increasing the height using the developer tool and see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

add `$` before script:

```
$(".ui-slider-handle").css("height", "100px");
```

Answer (score 0):

your jQuery is working fine.
you have to add span tag style first

```
.ui-slider-handle{
dispaly:block
}
```

or

add $ before script:

```
$(".ui-slider-handle").css("display", "block");
$(".ui-slider-handle").css("height", "100px");
```

Comment: Try setting the display property to "inline-block", not "block".
`$(".ui-slider-handle").css("display", "inline-block");`